# Calculate 3D Plane that Rests on a 3D Surface

Tags: python, scipy, 3d, interpolation, curve-fitting

I have about 300,000 points defining my 3D surface. I would like to know if I dropped a infinitely stiff sheet onto my 3D surface, what the equation of that plane would be. I know I need to find the 3 points the sheet would rest on as that defines a plane, but I'm not sure how to find my 3 points out of the ~300,000. You can assume this 3D surface is very bumpy and that this sheet will most likely lie on 3 "hills".

Edit: Some more background knowledge. This is point cloud data for a scan of a 3D surface which is nearly flat. What I would like to know is how this object would rest if I flipped it over and put it on a completely flat surface. I realize that this surface may be able to rest on the table in various different ways depending on the density and thickness of the object but you can assume the number of ways is finite and I would like to know all of the different ways just in case.

Edit: After looking at some point cloud libraries I'm thinking of doing something like computing the curvature using a kd tree (using SciPy) and only looking at regions that have a negative curvature and then there should be 3+ regions with negative curvature so some combinatorics + iterations should give the correct 3 points for the plane(s).

Comment: A fast approximation to the the entire data set would be to find the data points corresponding to max and min values for X and Y (of X, Y, Z) so that you have the data points for [minX, minY], [minX, maxY], [maxX, minY], maxX, maxY] - that is to say, the four extremes of X and Y. Fitting those four data points to the planar equation "Z = aX + bY + offset" should give a quick idea of what the final model should look like, and that approximation fit has the convenient aspect of being much easier to work with than the entire data set.

Comment: I've already fitted a plane to this data using least squares. It helps visualize it but I need to know how this object would rest on an extremely flat table.

Comment: That would involve rotation of the data, is that correct?

Comment: You could either rotate the data and try and find the rotation such that only 3 points cross the xy plane or find the plane that only intersects 3 points. Both equally hard as far as I can tell.

Comment: I understand. This should be possible with a non-linear fit to a flat surface, where the cost function has two components: A) the lowest sum of errors and B) all errors must be non-negative, Condition B) means that squaring the errors (to allow lowest sum-of-squared errors) is not necessary. I can provide example code using a "brick wall" in the cost function, which returns a large value (and therefore a large error) if a negative error value is found. Because the fitting algorithm cannot pass the large error this produces, it effectively runs into a "brick wall" that it cannot get over.

Comment: ...also note that the solution may not be unique.

Comment: and a mathematical solution might not work with a physical object if the centre of gravity comes into play

Comment: in general I doubt this is possible without more information about the 3D surface eg is it self intersecting? does it have a 'slant' to a prefered orientation (ie will your flat surface just slip off)? in a niave case you could just look for the highest 3 points in the cloud

Comment: @JamesPhillips I believe that would definitely work but it would be hard to figure out any other possible solutions.

Comment: @mikuszefski yes, you are correct and I realized that as well. However, once I know what plane(s) are possible, I can then calculate what the solid body looks like given a plane and I can assume a homogeneous density to determine the center of mass and whether if lying on this plane is stable. I basically have 2 scans of the surface of a nearly flat plate and the really flat table it is lying on. From these measurements I want to determine the thickness of the plate to see how flat it really is.

Comment: @DrBwts I have attached images of what the surface looks like. See the above comment, basically I am trying to find the thickness given two surface scans of a plate and the table the plate is lying on. Here's some plots of what this surface looks like. I believe this plate may have a unique plane but that may not be guaranteed for other plates: https://imgur.com/a/xznKXXK